# Endpoints for a WCF service not found

Tags: c#, json, wcf, endpoint

I created WCF service. when i test it with WCF Test Client , the service works fine.
I decided to configure the end point to display the result using the browser.

I have a blank page with the text **Endpoint not found.** with no more details.

Here is **my web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="mCollectorService.CollectorService" behaviorConfiguration="mCollectorService.CollectorServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="../CollectorService.svc"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="mCollectorService.ICollectorService"
              behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"
              />
  </service>
</services>


<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mCollectorService.CollectorServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehaviour">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Here is my **ICollectorService**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICollectorService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "Authenticate/{agentcode}/{pin}/{deviceIMEI}/{gpslat}/{gpslong}")]
    Authentification Authenticate(string agentcode,string pin, string deviceIMEI, string gpslat, string gpslong);

}
```

Any Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your Service like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="mCollectorService.CollectorService" behaviorConfiguration="mCollectorService.CollectorServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="../CollectorService.svc"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="mCollectorService.ICollectorService"
              behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"
              />
    <host>
       <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:51855/CollectorService.svc" />
       </baseAddresses>
</host>
  </service>
</services>
```

And Change your `OperationContract`

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICollectorService
{

   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "Authenticate/{agentcode}/{pin}/{deviceIMEI}/{gpslat}/{gpslong}")]
    Authentification Authenticate(string agentcode,string pin, string deviceIMEI, string gpslat, string gpslong);

}
```

And Call your URL in this way!

```
http://localhost:51855/CollectorService.svc/CollectorService.svc/Authenticate/YourAgentCode/YourPin/YourDeviceIMEI/YourGPSLat/YourGPSLong
```

Hope this will help. Thank You!

**EDIT:** I will recommend you to wrap your request in JSON instead of sending it in the Request URL if you are implementing **Authentication** mechanism.

Comment: i tried it as you sugested but nothing , still given the same result Endpoint not found.

Comment: i follow the example at [Mikes Knowledge base](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page2.htm)

Comment: Have you looked upon my EDIT notes?

Comment: yes, but the error was not related to the web.config. i was passing invalid escape character in the url (\). so he was giving that error

Comment: I know! This is why I said that instead of using URL Parameters, pass JSON which is a proper method. Otherwise use GET method. Anyhow, if it helped you than please accept this answer and edit this answer as per your need.

Comment: ok give me an example how i can pass it as json per your suggestion. i mean how to do that , thanks